# Table size and row count

Tags: postgresql

My database is in TB with different schemas. I would like to search in each schema following information:

- Schema name
- Table name
- Table size
- Rows count
- Table Created date

Where table name contains: `*.bak` or `dropped_*` or `*_drop`

Comment: What does "TB" stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tables appear as entries in `pg_catalog.pg_class`  that have `relkind='r'`
(see the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html)).

- table name: `pg_class.relname`
- schema name: `pg_namespace.nspname`. Join `pg_class.relnamespace` to `pg_namespace.oid` to follow the association between the table and its schema.
- table size: see `pg_relation_size(pg_class.oid)`
- row count: `pg_class.reltuples` gives an estimate. For an exact number, run select count(*) from the table.
- created date: the creation date is not recorded by postgres.

Some of these are also available through views in [`information_schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-schema.html) if you prefer. The structures of the views in this schema are dictated by the SQL standard, whereas the pg_catalog tables are postgres-specific.

### Example of query

Starting from the query provided as a comment:

```
  select nspname as schema, relname as tablename, 
  reltuples as rowcounts
  from pg_class c JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
   ON n.oid = c.relnamespace where relkind='r'
   and relname like '%_drop%'
   order by nspname, reltuples desc
```

remarks:

- The underscore character is a wildcard for the LIKE operator (it matches any character), so it needs to be quoted to be interpreted literally. By default, the quote character is backslash.
- pg_relation_size() as a function call can be introduced directly in the select list.

Amended query:

```
  select
    nspname as schema,
    relname as tablename, 
    reltuples as rowcounts,
    pg_relation_size(c.oid) AS tablesize
  from pg_class c JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
   ON n.oid = c.relnamespace where relkind='r'
   and relname like '%\_drop%'
   order by nspname, reltuples desc
```

Comment: Having a query would be helpful, I am using the following query:                                  select nspname as schema, relname as tablename, reltuples as rowcounts, 
from pg_class c
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
where relkind='r' and relname like '%_drop%'
order by nspname, reltuples desc;
On which column do I need to join table pg_relation_size(pg_class.oid)

Comment: @amanullah: see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The view `pg_statio_user_tables` is what you *really* want along with `pg_class` since `schema` is one of the column names.

This query tells you how big each portion of your tables are, including indices and toasts associated with tables.  It works on v12; don't know about older versions.

You'll need a wide window, and to adjust the formatting output as needed.

```
SELECT psu.schemaname as "schema", psu.relname AS table_name
    , to_char(sum(pg_total_relation_size(psu.relid)), '999,999,999,990') AS include_ndx
    , to_char(sum(pg_table_size(psu.relid)), '999,999,999,990') as whole_table
    , to_char(sum(pg_relation_size(psu.relid)), '99,999,999,990') AS not_toasts
    , to_char(sum(pg_table_size(psu.relid) - pg_relation_size(psu.relid)), '999,999,999,990') AS toasts
    , to_char(sum(pg_indexes_size(psu.relid)), '99,999,999,990') AS indexes
    , to_char(cl.reltuples, '999,999,990') as row_count
FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables psu
    , pg_catalog.pg_class cl
where psu.relid = cl.oid
group by psu.schemaname, psu.relname, cl.reltuples
order by 1
;
```